# How to store key value and delimeter in java

Tags: java

For the rule

```
a==b&c>=d|e<=f&!x==y
```

I want to split the rule using &,|,&! operator andt also want to store the operator.

So I want to store:

```
a==b
&
c>=d
|
e<=f
&!
x==y
```

Also should I store this in a string array?

Thanks.

Comment: Store it in whatever way makes sense for your program. Why do you need to split it? Is this the only string that needs to be split? Are there others similar that also need to be split?

Comment: are you looking for a standard API that achieves what you described?

Comment: The rule can have just &,|, &!. The operands like a==b etc can change.

Comment: Yes, it there a standard API or simple way to achieve this?

Comment: You may want to look at java.util.regex.Pattern and java.util.regex.Matcher classes for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
String data = "a==b&c>=d|e<=f&!x==y";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
        "&!"+  // &! 
        "|" +  // OR 
        "&" +  // & 
        "|" +  // OR
        "\\|"  // since | in regex is OR we need to use to backslashes 
               // before it -> \\| to turn off its special meaning
        );
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
while(m.find()){
    m.appendReplacement(sb, "\n"+m.group()+"\n");
}
m.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println(sb);
```

Output

```
a==b
&
c>=d
|
e<=f
&!
x==y
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex does what you want..

```
    final String input = "a==b&c>=d|e<=f&!x==y";

    //this regex will yield pairs of one string followed by operator (&, | or &!)...
    final String mainRegex = "(.*?)(&!|&|\\|)";

    final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(mainRegex).matcher(input);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
    }

    //...so we will need another regex to fetch what comes after the last operator
    final String lastOne = "(.*)(&|\\||!)(.*)";
    final Matcher lastOneMatcher = Pattern.compile(lastOne).matcher(input);

    if (lastOneMatcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(lastOneMatcher.group(3));
    }
```

Results in:

```
    a==b
    &
    c>=d
    |
    e<=f
    &!
    x==y
```

Answer (score 0):

It is achieavable in a one-liner, but it would involve a rather complex regex using both lookahead and lookbehind.

```
str.split("(?<=&!?|\\|)|(?=&!?|\\|)");
```

So what does this regex do?

The regex `&!?|\|` defines what is a valid operator, according to your rules. It basically reads out as "and `&`-sign optionally followed by an `!`-sign, OR a `|`-sign".

The other parts are the regex constructs lookahead and lookbehind, which are so called "zero width assertions".
`(?=a)` is a lookahead which looks ahead and ensures that the next character is an "a". E.g. it matches
a zero length string starting and ending between the "b" and the "a" in "foobar".

So, with the given regex argument, the split method call I proposed basically does:

Split at every position in the input string which is immediately before or after a `&`, a `&!` or a `|` sign.